# Displaying events - always allDay

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm displaying results from my db via JSON onto the calendar

A small example is as follows

`"start":"2013-11-12 14:00:00","end":"2013-11-12 15:00:00"` (ignore the start/end of the JSON)

This works fine and displays the event on the correct day.

When I switch to `agendaWeek` it displays the event as `allDay`

I know I can set a flag for `allDay` as being false, but these details are coming straight from the db.

In the `eventRender` function I have the following:

```
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');
$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm');
```

This doesn't seem to affect the rendering. All of the events are still `allDay`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you must set the `allDay` attribute to false, that it's usually true as configuration default; from the docs:

> true or false. Optional.
>
> Whether an event occurs at a specific time-of-day. This property
>   affects whether an event's time is shown. Also, in the agenda views,
>   determines if it is displayed in the "all-day" section.
>
> Don't include quotes around your true/false. This value is not a
>   string!
>
> When specifying Event Objects for events or eventSources, omitting
>   this property will make it inherit from allDayDefault, which is
>   normally true.

Code example:

```
var event = [{"title":"Timed event","start":"2013-11-12 14:00:00","end":"2013-11-12 15:00:00","allDay":false}];
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xc8yD/

Comment: But on the website: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ In the source there is as follows:     `{
     title: 'Click for Google',
     start: new Date(y, m, 28),
     end: new Date(y, m, 29),
     url: 'http://google.com/'
    }` This does not render as an allDay event if you see it on the actual calendar

Comment: Or is that because it isn't coming from JSON?

Comment: Just emphasize it -> it is VERY IMPORTANT to define the value (true/false) of the "allDay" parameter without colons like the code example above. If the value is "allDay":"true" or "allDay":"false", fullcalendar will ignore it.