# bootstrap full calender not working for day tab

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

My calendar is working properly. But in day section it's not showing the events from start time to end time its showing on full day only.

I am newbie here, help me in this, thanks in advance.

```
<div id="fullCalModal"  class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
                    <h4 id="modalTitle" style="text-align: center;" class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
               <h6>Description: </h6> <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body"></div><hr>
               <h6>Start Time: </h6><div id="starttime" class="modal-body"></div>
               <h6>End Time: </h6><div id="endtime" class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
    <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function()
                {
                    var currentDate = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>';
                    $('#custom-calendar').fullCalendar(
                      {
                        header:
                        {
                            left: 'prev,next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                        },
                        defaultDate: currentDate,
                        businessHours: true, 
                        editable: true,
                        events: <?= $response ?>,
                        eventClick:  function(events) {
                        $('#fullCalModal').modal('show');
                        $('#modalTitle').html(events.title);
                        $('#modalBody').html(events.details);
                        $('#starttime').html(events.stime);
                        $('#endtime').html(events.etime);

                  }
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

---

**Output**

In this image not showing start time to end time selection in day tab of my calendar. I want a selection if start date is from 2 O'clock and end date is 5 O'clock.

[image: Not working With day]

Comment: you can use any bootstrap calender library

Comment: @jawhar everything is working fine but only time not showing in day with particular event with particular time.

Comment: @gms0ulman i want solution not edited code.. if u have solution let me know.. otherwise dnt mark it

Comment: @Arushi Your question was flagged and in the edit queue - most likely because it's a new post. Check out the [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) parts of the StackOverflow model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying events - always allDay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265649/displaying-events-always-allday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to set the `allDay` attribute to `false`, that it's usually true as configuration default; from the docs:
See [Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265649/displaying-events-always-allday)